Failed to install Ubuntu on IdeaPad Slim 5 16IMH9 - Type 83DC
I have a new IdeaPad Slim 5 16IMH9 - Type 83DC
  Intel Core Ultra 5 125H
  1x 32GB LPD5X-7467
  1x 1 TB SSD PCIe
  1x Wi-Fi 6E 2x2 AX; Bluetooth 5.1 or above
  1x Intel Arc graphics
with no OS installed and tried to install from USB Ubuntu 24.04, 24.04.1 (pre-release), 24.10 (daily build) and none of them succeeded.
I was able to create the USB Boot drive for Ubuntu 24.04 from the ISO image downloaded. I have selected the "Try or install Ubuntu" on the GNU GRUB initial black screen. Usually I was able to get to the "Choose your language" screen or even beyond. Sometimes I was already getting Ubuntu crash messages at this point. The appearance of the problem was not consistent in time, so I cannot pinpoint at which stage of the installation it appeared and exactly describe what I was doing that caused the error.
Frequently I got to a gray screen saying Oh no! Something has gone wrong. and the only option is to log out.
No specific error messages.
Sometimes I am asked to send an error report, but event that one seems to be failing.
I have updated to the latest BIOS.
I have checked the hardware with Lenovo USB tools for any error, but everything is OK.
I have checked the downloaded files' integrity - no problem.
I was able to update the BIOS using Hiren's BootCD PE, and it worked nicely.
BTW - Fedora Workstation 40 failed as well.

Ubuntu 24.04.01 has been released, so I have tried it - no success. Please help me.
I am adding syslog information here.

Only questions about Ubuntu 24.04 are on topic. Unreleased and prerelease versions are not.

This question is similar to: Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for suggesting the similar question above, unfortunately it is not the case this time. I have edited my original question to provide further clarification on the installation steps I was able to get to.

I have a situation very similar to this, but for the non-prerelease 24.04.01 version. I have been searching around, and so far this is the only place I've seen the same error and being told to log out.

Can you give EndeavourOS a try? Since it has a recent kernel, it would have better support for recent hardware. In case it works in EndeavourOS, then Ubuntu will definitely support it within a year. https://endeavouros.com/
